# WiFi direct Connection Failed Error

Tags: wifi-direct

I am newbie in android. I wanted to create sample of P2P. For this i used WifiDirect sample that is provied by google in sdk. I run this sample on device having version 4.2 and I am able to list other devices. Devices get connected via WifiDirect. It shows option for gallery. When I select picture to send to another device , it gives me an error.

```
   `/wifidirectdemo(12880): failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 8088) after 500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`
```

While executing this line it gives me error:

```
socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(url, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
```

Please give me an idea or any help to sort it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the device you are using as the client is the wifi-direct connection host and therefore you are recieving a redundant IP from info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress() . Try running the client from the other device to you are using or getting a different IP from the info.